# Easiest way to create a MutableGuiceKeyToInstanceMap?

Tags: java, dictionary, guice, guava

I'd like to find or implement a `MutableGuiceKeyToInstanceMap` working just like `com.google.common.collect.MutableClassToInstanceMap` from Guava, but using `com.google.inject.Key<T>` from Guice in place of `Class<T>`.

I couldn't find it in Guice and I can't implement it the way `MutableClassToInstanceMap` was implemented because of its superclass `ConstrainedMap` being package-private. I can't use `MapConstraint.constrainedMap` either, since I would get no chance to add the methods `getInstance` and `putInstance` (and without them it's all quite pointless).

Making an own copy of the `ConstrainedMap` class would force me to copy quite a few additional classes, so this isn't the way to go. Making a helper Map via `MapConstraint.constrainedMap` and making `MutableGuiceKeyToInstanceMap extends ForwardingMap` which delegates everything to the helper could work, but it's still quite cumbersome. Any better idea?

Do you think proposing to make `ConstrainedMap` public is a good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you don't like the combination of `ForwardingMap` and `MapConstraint.constrainedMap`. The code is quite straightforward, and looks almost exactly like what you'd get if you were to extend `ConstrainedMap` directly:

```
import com.google.common.collect.ForwardingMap;
import com.google.common.collect.MapConstraint;
import com.google.common.collect.MapConstraints;
import com.google.inject.Key;
import org.apache.commons.lang.NotImplementedException;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public final class MutableGuiceKeyToInstanceMap<B>
        extends ForwardingMap<Key<? extends B>, B> {

    /**
     * Returns a new {@code MutableGuiceKeyToInstanceMap} instance backed by a {@link
     * java.util.HashMap} using the default initial capacity and load factor.
     */
    public static <B> MutableGuiceKeyToInstanceMap<B> create() {
        return new MutableGuiceKeyToInstanceMap<B>(new HashMap<Key<? extends B>, B>());
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new {@code MutableGuiceKeyToInstanceMap} instance backed by a given
     * empty {@code backingMap}. The caller surrenders control of the backing map,
     * and thus should not allow any direct references to it to remain accessible.
     */
    public static <B> MutableGuiceKeyToInstanceMap<B> create(Map<Key<? extends B>, B> backingMap) {
        return new MutableGuiceKeyToInstanceMap<B>(backingMap);
    }


    private final Map<Key<? extends B>, B> delegate;

    private MutableGuiceKeyToInstanceMap(Map<Key<? extends B>, B> delegate) {
        this.delegate = MapConstraints.constrainedMap(delegate, VALUE_MATCHES_GUICE_KEY);
    }

    @Override
    protected Map<Key<? extends B>, B> delegate() {
        return delegate;
    }

    private static final MapConstraint<Key<?>, Object> VALUE_MATCHES_GUICE_KEY = new MapConstraint<Key<?>, Object>() {
        @Override
        public void checkKeyValue(Key<?> key, Object value) {
            matchesGuiceKey(key, value);
        }
    };

    public <T extends B> T putInstance(Key<T> key, T value) {
        return matchesGuiceKey(key, put(key, value));
    }

    public <T extends B> T getInstance(Key<T> key) {
        return matchesGuiceKey(key, get(key));
    }

    private static <B, T extends B> T matchesGuiceKey(Key<T> key, B value) {
        throw new NotImplementedException("TODO");
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 0;
}
```

The code is pretty similar to `MutableClassToInstanceMap`, and there is no need to extend `ForwardingMap`... Sure, you need to add a `delegate()` method and its accompanying field, but the rest is identical.

I left out the `matchesGuiceKey()` implementation as an exercise for the reader. Good luck! You [might](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html) [need](http://blog.crazybob.org/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html) [it](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2007/05/limitation-of-super-type-tokens.html).

Comment: Nice answer, it's really not that bad. The method `matchesGuiceKey` may be a funny exercise, thx also for the links.

Comment: @eneveu: I don't think I've got the exercise right, as I'm using there `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") final Class<T> rawClass = (Class<T>) key.getTypeLiteral().getRawType();`. It seems to work, but any better idea?

Comment: Actually, implementing the `matchesGuiceKey` method is not easy. I was being ironic in my answer. Your question focused on the impossibility of extending `ConstrainedMap`, and I answered this part of the question. But the `matchesGuiceKey` stuff is actually harder. I tried implementing the method, but it was 1am, and I couldn't get it to work. I might try again later today, but generics are not going to make this easy ;) And don't even get me started on the whole `TypeLiteral` can of worm... Unless we find a generics expert?

Comment: @eneveu: I've implemented it [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4971686/110510/MgMutableGuiceKeyToInstanceMap.java). It may be wrong, but I don't think so. The result of method `TypeLiteral.getRawType()` requires an unchecked cast, but that's IMHO fine, as it returns something like raw `Map` for type literal like `Map<K, ? extends E super S>` and there's no way how to express their relationship in the Java generics system.

Comment: @eneveu: There's only one problem remaining: Something like `m.put(stringListKey, integerList);` should not be possible, but -- because of erasure -- it is, and there's no way around it, except forbidding all mutators other then `putInstance`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was afraid of. Because of type erasure, you cannot be totally foolproof with generics... `MutableClassToInstanceMap` has the same problem :(

Answer (score 2):

Some thoughts:

1. I'm curious why you want to do this.
2. A `ForwardingMap` seems fine for this. What's cumbersome about it?
3. Making `ConstrainedMap` public would not be a good idea.

Comment: 1. For implementing a custom scope. OK, it's not actually needed, since there's nobody, who could put anything wrong there in. 2. This way I define two nearly identical classes - one of them just in order to have something to forward to. But it's not as bad as I thought. 3. Why not?

Comment: 1. I actually need only the two methods `getInstance` and `putInstance`, none of the Map methods is needed. However, I wanted to make a Map (no idea how to call such a "map" lacking all the Map methods). 2. It's actually really easy. 3. I see that in order to maintain the constraint, it must be either package-private or all mutating and mutator-exposing methods (like `entrySet()`) must be final.